# Are there any alternative programs to Proteus available?

Tags: 11.10, software-recommendation

I'm using Ubuntu 11.10 on my machine and I want to install some programs such as the windows program "proteus" and I can't install them on my machine.

I searched a lot and a lot for solution but have not found an acceptable answer.
I don't have enough space to install windows beside of Linux.
I also know that wine can run windows application but it doesn't work for me.

If any of you know alternative program for Proteus. I would appreciate that.

Comment: if you only want to use windows software then use a windows OS.  However, if you want to understand if there are alternatives (often better) then please reword your question.

Comment: You can also use `wineHQ` for installing windows software
or 
`tryton-proteus` binary package in Ubuntu Oneiric amd64

Comment: in fact if there are alternative programs for 1-proteus ...2-mikroC....3-visual studio ... it would be better .

Comment: the way this site works is a question and answer format - so individual questions is better.  I'll reword your question for you to clarify what I'm saying.

Comment: Are you referring to the circuit board software?

Answer (score 8):

If you are talking about the medical software; then this is a link to a Linux version:

> http://www.proteme.org/download3.html

If you are talking a PCB design software the following are potential alternatives:

- KiCad
- PCB Designer
- gEDA
- Visolate
- [Fritzing](http://fritzing.org/)

They are all available in the software center.

Comment: thanks for your reply ..but proteus isnot just a program to design circuits .. it's fully simulation...dealing with pic ..microcontroller ..and a lot of other staff .. so i don't think that those program are enough.. but i have installed windows 7 (despite it's not what i wanted to do )but i think that this is the best solution .. thank you again .

Answer (score 6):

it runs ok on wine, no errors works great with my ATI adapter, and i've simulated PIC microcontroller on it all fine.
^^! just type in terminal

```
sudo apt-get install wine
```

Answer (score 2):

[KTechlab](https://github.com/ktechlab/ktechlab/wiki) will be a better alternative

Answer (score 2):

First of all, it's sad to see some of the folks here suggest using wine or a virtual machine. Not only is it an inappropriate answer to the question, but also, in my humble opinion, it is against the spirit of the Ubuntu community to use and promote proprietary Windows software.

But back to your question, Proteus has two famous products [Proteus PCB](https://alternativeto.net/software/proteus-pcb-design/?license=opensource), which is an EDA suite (electronic design automation) and [Proteus VSM](https://alternativeto.net/software/proteus-vsm/) for analog circuits and microcontroller (MCU) simulation. You did not mention which one you are referring to. Still, people usually look for VSM alternatives as it is a great software for simulating MCUs and the Arduino AVR development board. Unfortunately, there are not many cross-platform free, liquid, and open-source software (FLOSS) as powerful and feature-rich as Proteus VSM, but there are some attempts. I will try to list them here:

- KTechLab
- SimulIDE
- BrainBox
- PICsimLab or PICsim
- [PIC-Simulator](https://github.com/PalatinCoder/PIC-Simulator)
- [simavr](https://github.com/buserror/simavr)
- [SimulAVR](http://www.nongnu.org/simulavr/) and simulavr-disp
- [SPICE](https://ptolemy.berkeley.edu/projects/embedded/pubs/downloads/spice/) (Simulation Program with Integrated Circuit Emphasis)
- QUCS (Quite Universal Circuit Simulator), Qucs-S, Qucsstudio, Qucsator
- Ngspice, Spice3f5, Cider1b1, and Xspice
- Xyce
- Circuit Simulator or [CircuitJS1](https://github.com/pfalstad/circuitjs1)

**P.S.** I have created a curated list of all FLOSS electrical engineering software [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/electronics/comments/ap6m45/curated_list_of_awesome_free_and_open_source/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x).

Answer (score 1):

If you want, you can install Proteus 7.0 which is functional on Ubuntu 12.04 (32bits)  with Wine or PlayonLinux. However, **newer** versions (7.5 or 8.0) won't work since wine finishes with errors during execution.

For your reading pleasure, here is my answer in French:

Salut, si tu veux encore installer Proteus-Isis, je te recommande la version 7.0 qui est fonctionnel sur ubuntu 12.04 avec Wine ou PlayonLinux.Cependant,pour les nouvelles versions (7.5 ou 8.0) Wine fini par des erreurs lors de l'exécution.
Contente toi avec ce qui fonctionne sans te casser trop la tête, espérons que les prochaines mise à jours apporteront plus de liberté !

Answer (score 0):

Wine is good but not enough for such complex software as Proteus.
I installed CrossOver (based on Wine), and install Proteus on it successfully.