# How to install Proteus( simulation software) for ubuntu

Tags: 14.04

I need Proteus to check some of the circuits I have been working on, but I couldn't find it in software center and its official site. I have just shifted from windows (where I had been using proteus), so don't know where else to search for it.

visit http://www.labcenter.com/index.cfm

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Proteus is not available for Linux natively.

Although you may be successful in running it through WINE, there is no guarantee that all the features will work, especially since it is a software that requires a lot of libraries to simulate various microcontrollers etc.

The best option to run Windows software which do not have Linux ports is to install a Windows OS, either on a separate partition or as a virtual machine.

Otherwise, you may wish to look at [alternatives to Proteus on Linux](https://askubuntu.com/questions/77399/are-there-any-alternative-programs-to-proteus-available).

Answer (score 1):

looks like labcenter is not providing a linux version of their product.
Search for alternatives or try using "Wine" to install the windows version.
you can find how to use wine all over the internet.
inshort:
open software center
search wine
install wine
open command prompt
type    wine /path/to/install_file.exe

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to use virtual machine :

1. Install a virtual machine like VirtualBox or VMWare on your Ubuntu OS
2. Install a windows OS inside it
3. Install Proteus on your virtual windows and use it

Answer (score 0):

you can install wine windows program loader before install Proteus ,
you can able to run every windows program after install wine

Comment: Not every windows program is running with wine.