# Cannot open network adapter

Tags: permissions, wine, sockets

I am running a simulation software installed using `wine`, but when I run a demo, it says:

> cannot open network adapter: any: you don't have permission to capture on that device(socket: operation not permitted).

[image: error screenshot]

Comment: What happens when you use sudo wine [programName] ?

Comment: It says "wine: /home/jeevansai/.wine is not owned by you".

Comment: Seems like a restriction from sharing wine with several users. This is probably good, since running wine with sudo could introduce a security risk. Sorry, I dont have an answer to your original question. What program are you trying to run through wine?

Comment: proteus software, i am trying to connect arduino to internet with ethernet controller.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to install/get proteus( simulation software) for ubuntu](http://askubuntu.com/questions/565125/how-to-install-get-proteus-simulation-software-for-ubuntu)

Comment: I have installed the software but i am getting an error in one design where i want to use sockets

Answer (score 0):

Wine is a compatibility layer that allows some Windows software to run under Linux.

It isn't for drivers or any other software requiring direct hardware access. Your simulation software seems to require it hence the `cannot open network adapter` error message.

A similar Linux native software is needed for the purpose.

Comment: can i give the software permission to create and capture sockets

Comment: I found this in wine documentation "Wine uses the Unix drivers to access the various hardware pieces on the box"